# Можно ли разбить SUPERVISOR на 3 части?

Tags: linux, supervisord

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли установить несколько супервизоров на одной машине. Сейчас установлен один, хочется разбить информацию на 3 супервизора.

Comment: Почему бы и нет, просто заведите три разных конфига на разных портах

Comment: а как понять к какому конфигу будет обращаться супервизор?

Comment: и где будут располагаться эти конфиги? Ведь есть папка supervisor, в ней лежит supervisord.conf, остальные же надо класть в другое место наверное

Comment: Вы явно укажете нужный конфиг-файл в аргументах командной строки при запуске супервизора. Располагаться — да где хотите

Comment: Все настройки запуска вы можете прочитать в [родной справке супервизора](http://supervisord.org/running.html#supervisord-command-line-options). Для сравнения, системный супервизор в Debian/Ubuntu запускается командой `/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` — и в общем-то достаточно просто взять эту команду и просто другой путь к конфигу прописать. Можно ещё опцию `-n` дописать чтобы супервизор не сворачивался в демона если это не нужно

Comment: то есть три супервизора не нужно будет устанавливать?

Comment: Нет, один супервизор три раза с разными конфигами запустить

Comment: Спасибо большое!